# Data change not identified on re-visiting an old tab

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-template, angular2-services

i'm new to Angular 2 and was working with bootstrap tabs. I'll have to fetch data from server when a tab is changed. Here comes the problem, when the page is initially loaded and on a specific tab the data loads fine. When i switch tabs, i can see the onInit() method being called and data being fetched, but nothing displayed. 
When i go to another tab and come back to the previous tab, i can again see onInit() being called, data being fetched but nothing displayed. 

I've made each tab as one component and the routing is working perfectly fine as well. 

Appreciate the help. 

Here is the code (posted only one of five child components) ->

AppComponent.html

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<!-- tab bar layout-->
<!-- nv tab -->
<div class="row" id="tabs">
  <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-justified">
    <li class="active"><a href="#user" data-toggle="tab">Users</a></li>
    <li><a href="#page" data-toggle="tab">Pages</a></li>
    <li><a href="#event" data-toggle="tab">Events</a></li>
    <li><a href="#place" data-toggle="tab">Places</a></li>
    <li><a href="#group" data-toggle="tab">Groups</a></li>
    <li><a href="#favorite" data-toggle="tab">Favorites</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <hr style="border: 1px solid #337ab5; margin-top: 0px;">
</div>    
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

SearchComponent.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

import { FetchDataService } from '../fetch-data.service';

@Component({
 selector: 'app-search',
 templateUrl: './search.component.html',
 styleUrls: ['./search.component.css']
})
export class SearchComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

private subscription;

jsonResult = new Array();

constructor(private dataService: FetchDataService, private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) {}    

private loadData(): void {
  this.subscription = this.dataService.getSearchedUsers(searchedKeyword)
          .subscribe(
            userSearchData => {
              //console.log(userSearchData)
              this.jsonResult = userSearchData;
            },
            error => console.log(error),
            () => console.log("Completed!"));
}

ngOnInit() : void {
  console.log("On init called");
  // subscribe to listen for search requests
  this.activatedRoute.params
                     .map(params => params['query'])
                     .subscribe(data => 
                        { this.loadData(data);}, 
                      error => 
                        { console.log(error); }
                      );   
}

ngOnDestroy(): void {
  this.subscription.unsubscribe();
  console.log("On destroy called");
}
}
```

SearchComponent.html

```
{{ jsonResult.length }}
<ul *ngFor="let result of jsonResult" >
  <li>{{result.id}}</li>
  <li>{{result.name}}</li>
  <li>{{result.score}}</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: What is the purpose of this map statement? .map(params => params['query'])

Comment: router actively listens for changes in the url, i.e. it's an observable. Map operator converts the params object to a get a specific value of the key called 'query' defined in the router.ts file.

Comment: Put it in a plunker..